# Lazy load or image loading sequence questions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a task given by our project manager.
Basically he wants to load image sequentially. When the page first load, he wants certain sequence on the load process.
Although I already explained on how the browser works and created javascript that display certain sequence display, it doesn't seem to fit the requirements.

What he wants is if it's possible to use "lazy load method" when the page first started.

I know lazy load image is used if we have a long page(scrolling) and many pictures. User might not see all the pictures below, so it kinda wasting bandwith if everything load at once during web loading.
Thus, we use lazy load image, that images will be loaded when user scroll the page.

The question is if it's possible to apply this method at the first start of the page. So we can directly select the sequence and have the lazy load working even on the first display of the page without scrolling.

Lazy load that I used is =  http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload
https://raw.github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/master/jquery.lazyload.js

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Yep just include the lazy load initialization in a ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("img.className").lazyload({
        container: $("#DivId"),
    });

});
```